# Jenkins is not running on mac machine

Tags: jenkins

After setup when I am running the following command

```
tail -f /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log
```

I get the following error :

```
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Jenkins has failed to create a temporary file in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp
    at Main.extractFromJar(Main.java:437)
    at Main._main(Main.java:248)
    at Main.main(Main.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
    at Main.extractFromJar(Main.java:434)
    ... 2 more
2018-06-24 02:41:30.683 defaults[7313:921611] 
The domain/default pair of (/Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci, war) does not exist
2018-06-24 02:41:30.778 defaults[7319:921636] 
The domain/default pair of (/Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci, JENKINS_HOME) does not exist
2018-06-24 02:41:30.794 defaults[7320:921640] 
The domain/default pair of (/Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci, prefix) does not exist
2018-06-24 02:41:30.826 defaults[7322:921648] 
The domain/default pair of (/Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci, httpListenAddress) does not exist
2018-06-24 02:41:30.842 defaults[7323:921652] 
The domain/default pair of (/Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci, httpsPort) does not exist
2018-06-24 02:41:30.858 defaults[7324:921656] 
The domain/default pair of (/Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci, httpsListenAddress) does not exist
2018-06-24 02:41:30.876 defaults[7325:921660] 
The domain/default pair of (/Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci, httpsKeyStore) does not exist
2018-06-24 02:41:30.891 defaults[7326:921664] 
The domain/default pair of (/Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci, httpsKeyStorePassword) does not exist
JENKINS_HOME=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home
Jenkins command line for execution:
/usr/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp -jar /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war --httpPort=8080
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Running from: /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war
```

My plist file is as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log</string>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>JENKINS_HOME</key>
      <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home</string>
      <key>JAVA_HOME</key>
      <string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home</string>
    </dict>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>daemon</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.jenkins-ci</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/bin/bash</string>
      <string>/Library/Application Support/Jenkins/jenkins-runner.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>jenkins</string>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Is there any way I can fix to make it work?

Comment: does it fail even if you run with 'sudo'?

Comment: The user you are running Jenkins with doesn't have enough rights to write to /Users/shared/Jenkins/tmp.  That's exactly what the error message is saying.

Comment: @Simon I am already using `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist` command to run jenkins

Comment: @Simon /Users/Shared/Jenkins has `drwxr-xr-x` permission